# Parse.com returns empty objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an NSArray called "malls" that contains a large number of NSDictionaries (each a specific mall) that I uploaded to Parse.com. I want my users to be able to access this information to create map annotations.

I've tried to do this in 2 different ways:

1. I tried uploading the entire array as a property of a single object:

this is the upload:

in the dataBank.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* malls;
```

in the .m file

```
PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"malls"];
obj[@"mallsData"] = self.malls;
[obj saveInBackground];
```

I try to get the data from parse:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)createAnnotationsFromParse
{
    __block NSMutableArray* data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    __block NSMutableArray* annots = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"malls"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"Eaib9yfTRe" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    data = [object objectForKey:@"mallsData"];
    annots = [self createAnnotations:data];
}];

return annots;
}
```

The problem is getObjectInBackground is asynchronous and always returns before getting the data from the server. I tried moving the "return annots" inside the code block but that gives the following error: "incompatible block pointer types".

2. I uploaded 5 "mall" objects to class "malls2". Each object has 2 properties- name and address:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       PFObject *mallsObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"malls2"];
       mallsObj[name] = [[self.malls objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:name];
       mallsObj[address] = [[self.malls objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:address];
       [mallsObj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       if(succeeded)
           NSLog(@"yay");
       else
           NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
   }];
   ```

   }

then I try to get it back:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)createAnnotationsFromParse
{
    __block Annotation* anno = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    __block NSMutableArray* annots = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"malls2"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,  NSError *error) {
        if(error)
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++)
            {
                    //createAnnotationWithTitle is a func in a different class that creates the annotation
                    anno = [anno createAnnotationWithTitle:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:name] andAddress:[[objects objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:address]];
            }
            [annots addObject:anno];
        }
    }];

    return annots;
}
```

I get 5 objects but they're all empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It looked like I was getting "empty objects" (can be seen here postimg.org/image/ot7ehn29b ) but once I tried to access data from the objects I saw there was no problem. Basiclly I was tricked by the PFObjects in the array showing "0 objects" and assumed it meant they came back from Parse.com empty. Here's how I checked, just for reference:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"malls2"];
NSArray *array = [query findObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]; // I have a string property called "name" in my Parse object.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic misunderstanding about asynchronous methods with block parameters.  The trick is to get out of the habit of thinking that code that appears later in a source file runs later.  The assumption works in this function:

```
- (void)regularFunction {
    // these NSLogs run top to bottom
    NSLog(@"first");
    NSLog(@"second");
    NSLog(@"third");
}
```

This will generate logs: first, second, third.  Top to bottom, but not in this one:

```
- (void)functionThatMakesAsynchCall {
    // these NSLogs do not run top to bottom
    NSLog(@"first");
    [someObject doSomeAsynchThing:^{
        NSLog(@"second");
    }];
    NSLog(@"third");
}
```

That function will generate logs - first, third, second.  The "second" NSLog will run well after the "third" one.

So what should you do?  Don't try to update the UI with results of a parse call until after it completes, like this:

```
// declared void because we can't return anything useful
- (void)doSomeParseThing {
    // if you change the UI here, change it to say: "we're busy calling parse"
    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"malls2"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,  NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            // change the UI here, say by setting the datasource to a UITableView
            // equal to the objects block parameter
        }
    }];

    // don't bother changing the UI here
    // don't bother returning anything here
    // we just started the request
}
```

But what if `doSomeParseThing` is really a model function, whose only job is to fetch from parse, not to know anything about UI?  That's a very reasonable idea.  To solve it, you need to build your model method the way parse built their's, with block parameter:

```
// in MyModel.m
// declared void because we can't return anything useful
+ (void)doSomeParseThing:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block {
    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"malls2"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,  NSError *error) {
        block(objects, error);
    }];
}
```

Now your view controller can call, leave the query work to your model and the UI work to the vc:

```
// change UI to 'busy' here
[MyModel doSomeParseThing:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // update UI with objects or error here
}];
```

Comment: I've copied the  + (void)doSomeParseThing:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))block  to my dataBank (which would be the modal I think) and the [MyModel doSomeParseThing:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) to my mapView VC, but I still get empty objects returned.

I feel like I'm missing something here, isn't there a simple way of getting uploaded data back from parse? surely there's an easy and simple way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by empty?  Can you nslog what you get and post that?  Also, can you post an image of malls2 from the pArse data browser?

Comment: This is the NSLog of the objects: 2015-05-18 19:04:38.231 ifp 2nd draft[30199:1300788] <malls2: 0x7ff34f0dd940, objectId: pMCrZnay2v, localId: (null)> {
    address = "\U05d4\U05e1\U05ea\U05ea 20 \U05d0\U05d9\U05dc\U05ea \U05d9\U05e9\U05e8\U05d0\U05dc";
    name = "\U05d1\U05d9\U05d2 \U05d0\U05d9\U05dc\U05ea";
}
And this is the malls2 class from Parse.com:
http://postimg.org/image/drvp4isx7/
Please show me the generic way to download the objects in malls2 from Parse to my local device, that will help me a lot I think. Thanks for your help!