# why return value is null , when the return type is null in iOS, objectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, return-value, return-type

I'm getting data from webservice.this is my code

```
- (NSArray *)setupConnection
{
    airportArray = nil;
    NSString *airportCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"somevalue"];
    NSString *authenticationCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"somenumber"];
    NSString *baseurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl",authenticationCode,airportCode];
//    NSString *mainurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
//    NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlString];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseurl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSArray *mainArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        airportArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *all in mainArray) {
            airports = [all objectForKey:@"something"];

            [airportArray addObject:airports];
            NSLog(@"%@", airports);//**this prints the value**
        }


        //NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        UIAlertController *mainAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:mainAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];



    return airportArray;//**this returns null**
}
```

I checked with this, but it is null

```
- (void)printap
{
    NSArray *chk = [self setupConnection];
    NSLog(@"CHK :%@", chk);
}
```

when print it prints the value. but when I return it is null.why is that.help me with this

Comment: because you are requesting data asynchronously, at the point where you return something, the server has not responded yet and the array is therefore still not populated. Set up a completionBlock as input parameter of your `setupConnection` method and call that method when the actual request finished.

Comment: so what should I do, I'm new to this. help me with this

Comment: Perform your data operations in success block of the async operation. Either that or use synchronous calls

Comment: Google it, that has been asked hundreds of times before. For example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280026/parse-com-returns-empty-objects

Comment: These links will help you out : [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180552/implementing-a-method-taking-a-block-to-use-as-callback), [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html), [link3](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/) and [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=callback%20block%20ios)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to use callback block.

Below is a example for your provided code.

In header file

```
typedef void(^FailureBlock)(NSError *error);
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)(NSArray *responseArray);
```

In implementation file

```
@implementation BSANetworkController {

    FailureBlock _failureBlock;

    SuccessBlock _successBlock;

}

- (void)setupConnectionWithsuccess:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure;

    //your code...

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseurl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSArray *mainArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        airportArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *all in mainArray) {
            airports = [all objectForKey:@"something"];

            [airportArray addObject:airports];
            NSLog(@"%@", airports);//**this prints the value**
        }

   if (_successBlock) {

        _successBlock(airports); //Change the type as per your need

    }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (_failureBlock) {

            _failureBlock(error);

        }

    }];

}  

- (void)printap
{

   [self setupConnectionWithsuccess:^(NSArray *array) {

          NSLog(@"CHK :%@", array);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

           UIAlertController *mainAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
           [self presentViewController:mainAlert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
        }

    }];
  }
```

Read about it in below links.

1. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180552/implementing-a-method-taking-a-block-to-use-as-callback)
2. [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)
3. [link3](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/)
4. [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=callback%20block%20ios)

Comment: Just posting links can easily be done in comments, not as an answer.

Comment: @luk2302 - Well now I have added the code for his understanding. Is it good to go?

Comment: Yes, that is better!

Comment: @subash - this is a example for your understanding but you need to read about block in iOS that way you will have better understand about callback in iOS. Check the links provided in comments